# Abnormal presence of code after __stack_chk_fail

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, disassembly, ida

I have an 64-bits ELF binary. I don't have its source code, don't know with which parameters it was compiled, and am not allowed to provide it here. The only relevant information I have is that the source is a .c file (so no hand-crafted assembly), compiled through a Makefile.

While reversing this binary using IDA, I stumbled upon an extremely weird construction I have never seen before and absolutely cannot explain. Here is the raw decompilation of one function with IDA syntax:

```
mov    rax, [rsp+var_20]
xor    rax, fs:28h
jnz    location
add    rsp, 28h
pop    rbx
pop    rbp
retn

location:
call    __stack_chk_fail
nop     dword ptr [rax]
db      2Eh
nop     word ptr [rax+rax+00000000h]
...then dozens of instructions of normal and functional code
```

Here, we have a simple canary check, where we return if it is valid, and call `__stack_chk_fail` otherwise. Everything is perfectly normal. But after this check, there is still assembly, and of fully-functional code.

Looking at the manual of `__stack_chk_fail`, I made sure that this function does exit the program, and that there is no edge case where it could continue:

> Description
>
> The interface __stack_chk_fail() shall abort the function that called it with a message that a stack overflow has been detected. The program that called the function shall then exit.

I also tried to write this small C program, to search for a method to reproduce this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo()
{
        int a = 3;
        printf("%d\n", a);

        return 0;

        int b = 7;
        printf("%d\n", b);
}

int main()
{
        foo();
        return 0;
}
```

But the code after the `return` is simply omitted by gcc.

It does not appear either that my binary is vulnerable to a buffer overflow that I could exploit to control `rip` and jump to the code after the canary check. I also inspected every `call` and jumps using `objdump`, and this code seems to never be called.

Could someone explain what is going on? How was this code generated in the first place? Is it a joke from the author of the binary?

Comment: It's padding.  `2E` is an ineffective prefix applied to make the following instruction longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are looking at padding, followed by an unrelated function that IDA does not have a name for.

To test this hypothesis, I need the following additional information:

- The address of the byte immediately after `call __stack_chk_fail`.
- The next higher address that is the target of a call or jump instruction.
- A raw hex dump of the bytes in between those two addresses.
- The disassembly of four or five instructions starting at the next higher address that is the target of a call or jump instruction.

Comment: The address of the `nop` immediately after `__stack_chk_fail` is 0x401333, while the address of the first instruction after the padding is 0x401340 (so an aligned one). The next address target by a jump or call is 0x4015cf, a bit far, so I'm not sure if a dump of all the bytes between would be useful to you. Your hypothesis is probably right, since the instructions after 0x401340 are a function prologue and canary creation. It seems it is an error from IDA: I'll try to correct it. It doesn't change the fact that this function is never called, however.

Comment: Functions that are never called do end up in binaries all the time -- by default most linkers only prune unused data on a per-_object file_ basis.